# EXC_BAD_ACCES in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

getting a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCES(code=2, adress=0xbf7fffffc)" error at

```
NSArray *tempArray ] [lijstString componentsSeperatedByString:@","];
```

What can i do about this?

This is the whole codepart:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)lijstArray{
NSString *lijstString = self.details[@"lijst"];
NSArray  *tempArray   = [lijstString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

self.lijstArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *lijstValue in tempArray) {
    [self.lijstArray addObject:[lijstValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
    return self.lijstArray;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what happens if you run `NSLog(@"%@", lijstString);` after you assign it with `self.details[@"lijst"];`?

Comment: @Logan 2014-04-20 00:26:07.193 shoppinglist[50925:60b] eieren, kaas, melk, 2 uien, brood(volkoren)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)lijstArray{
    if(!_lijstArray){ //If you need get new lijstArray always, comment this line, and below "}"
        NSString *lijstString = self.details[@"lijst"];
        NSArray  *tempArray   = [lijstString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
        _lijstArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *lijstValue in tempArray) {
             [_lijstArray addObject:[lijstValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
        }
    }
    return _lijstArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `lijstArray` getter function is infinitely recursive.  Assuming lijstArray is an @property, every time you use `self.lijstArray` you are calling the instance method `lijstArray` if used as a getter or `setLijstArray` if used as a setter.

You are using `self.lijstArray` three times. The first use on the left part of the assignment operator is only calling `[self setLijstArray: ... ]` so while that will trample the `_lijstArray` iVar, it will not cause recursion.

You cause recursion in two places, though once is enough.  First is with `[self.lijstArray addObject: ... ]` which is the same as `[[self lijstArray] addObject: ... ]`.  This causes infinite recursion.

And then with `return self.lijstArray` which is the same as `return [self lijstArray]` -- again the lijstArray instance method is calling itself.  This also causes infinite recursion.

Incidentally the stack trace would be informative-- you'd have a very deep stack.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the line:

```
self.details[@"list"];
```

Is not null. Also check to make sure tempArray and lijstString are being allocated and initialized.

Comment: self.details[@"list"]; is not null. because i use it for other stuff swell. If i NSlog the details[@"lijst"] i think this is causing me the stack overflow, cuz it just gives me thousands of lines of the same thing.